# Creating a Play/Pause button with pure HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, button, audio, graphics

Here is what I currently have:

```css
#player:checked + label + div { display: none;}
#player + label:after { content: "▶" ;}
#player:checked + label:after { content: "❚❚";}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FD749B;
}
```

```html
<audio><source src="INSERT AUDIO.MP3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>



<input type="checkbox" 
style='display: none' 
id=player 
onclick=
'var a = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
if(a.paused)a.play();else a.pause()'>
<label for=player></label>
```

This works fine, however the site I'm trying to use this on doesn't like this section:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
if(a.paused) a.play();
else a.pause()
```

And as such, the button will not play audio.

I'm trying to find a way to keep this code relatively the same, but eliminate the need for that var javascript section

Does anyone know any methods that'll only use HTML and CSS?

Comment: `doesn't like this section`, this is too vague. What's the exact issue? It's working well here : https://jsfiddle.net/tza693oe/

Comment: As I said, audio doesn't play on the specific site I'm working this code into, as javascript is disabled there.

Comment: `javascript is disabled there` this is actually a key piece of information for us. Nonetheless, there's no way I know of to do what you ask with only HTML and CSS.